# Is there a limit to number of pages displayed for selection in custom menu?

Tags: menus

I recently started working with a client who has over 400 pages on their WP site (yes, pages, not posts). Their menu needs to be redone, so I decided to go the 'custom menus' route. However, not more than a third of the pages are available to select from the 'Pages' meta box on the Menus page. And 'search' does not seem to work (typing in the page title, even of pages that do show in the box, results in 'No results found' message.

In short, some of the pages I need to add to the menu are not available for me to select. What's up with this? And how do I solve it?

Also, if I select on-site pages as 'custom links', will WP still add classes to the links to indicate they are 'current page' or 'current page ancestor'?

Comment: If you add this as answer, you can also mark it as solution 2 days later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to 3.1 from 3.05 and both problems (inability to see all pages in 'pages' box, and inability to search) went away.